# Entering '=' as the first character in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that runs and often needs to have "=" as the first character in a cell. Cells are filled with such values as "= Domestic", "<> Domestic", etc.

Right now I am replacing "=" with "IS" as a quickfix, but I would like it if I could keep the equal sign, for consistency with cells that use symbols such as "<>". When I try, Excel thinks it is a function with the wrong syntax. I am using `Cells(row, col).Value = x`, where `x` is the string that may or may not start with "=", to enter the data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a single quote `'` at the start of the string:

```
Cells(row, col).Value = "'" & x
```

and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 6):

This is an alternate method

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = Range("C:C") 'Column "C"
    myRange.NumberFormat = "@" 'Set cell format of range to plain text
    myRange.Cells(1, 1) = "= Domestic"

End Sub
```

Compared to manji's answer, it provides no performance or size enhancement...just different.