# VBA not handling "bad" characters when inserting values into spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code to insert values from my result set into my spreadsheet:

```
    Rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Rst.EOF = False
    For i = 0 To Rst.Fields.Count - 1
        ActiveCell.Value = Rst.Fields(i).Value  'insert value into cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate        'move to next cell for next value
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -i).Activate           'move to next row for next record
    Rst.MoveNext
    Loop
```

The problem I'm running into is that some users are using `=` as the first character in their input, and excel does not like that ("Application-defined or object-defined error").

I've seen the workaround for [Entering '=' as the first character in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458941/vba-entering-as-the-first-character-in-a-cell) but I don't want to apply the `'` to every field, ideally only if it starts with `=`.

I need a solution that also works with Null values. I've tried a bunch of different combinations (IsNull, IsDBNull), but I can't seem to find one that works.

Comment: The link you show also has an answer suggesting to set the cell format to "text" before adding a value which starts with `=`  That doesn't work for you?

Comment: Great call, @TimWilliams -- I set the range of user input cells to plaintext and VBA was happy! If you'd like to convert it to an answer, I'd accept it. Otherwise, maybe just close as duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @timwilliams suggested, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6459408/347455) to set the format of the range (seems more efficient than @tompage's cell-by-cell approach) to text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sitting on a Linux box right now so I can't test this but from memory...

If you set the Number format of the cell to "@"  before you assign the value then that should mean that it takes values as literal strings

This also means that "0131" won't be changed to 131

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"  ' This Cell will hold text
ActiveCell.Value = Rst.Fields(i).Value  'insert value into cell
```

You could put the formating within an If Statement based on Rst.Fields(i).Type if you only want to do this for text fields