# Enter value as text to cell using VBA even if value starts with =?

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error on the following expression:

```
wksWrite.Cells(lWriteRow, "F") = Trim(wksRead.Cells(lReadRow, 2))
```

because `Trim(wksRead.Cells(lReadRow, 2))` evaluates to:

```
=SKYDDSFOLIE FÖR SR-72 5424
```

I guess Excel evaluates that as a formula and doesn't allow VBA to enter it. But I want to enter that value as text. I tried adding:

```
    wksWrite.Cells(lWriteRow, "B").NumberFormat = "@"
    wksWrite.Cells(lWriteRow, "F").Value = CStr(Trim(wksRead.Cells(lReadRow, 2)))
```

But I still get the same error. How can I force Excel to interpret the value as text and accept it?

Comment: Why are you not defining the property of the cell using `.Value`, `.Text`, or `.Formula`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Entering '=' as the first character in a cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458941/vba-entering-as-the-first-character-in-a-cell)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Single Quotes before the value making it treat as a String,

```
wksWrite.Cells(lWriteRow, "F") = "'" & Trim(wksRead.Cells(lReadRow, 2))
```